# random number generation from a copula using set.seed

Tags: r, random, random-seed

I'm running two sessions of RStudio on my laptop.

When I ran

```
set.seed(1)
runif(1)
```

twice in each session, four of them gave the same number 0.2655087.

But if I generate random numbers from a copula using `rCopula` function of `copula` package, it does not work. It produces the same numbers if I run it twice within the same session, but different numbers in a different session.

On session 1,

```
set.seed(5)  
dat = rCopula(50, gumbelCopula(2.07, dim = 2))
dat[1,]
# [1] 0.7058623 0.3512414
set.seed(5)  
dat = rCopula(50, gumbelCopula(2.07, dim = 2))
dat[1,]
# [1] 0.7058623 0.3512414
```

On session 2,

```
set.seed(5)
dat = rCopula(50, gumbelCopula(2.07, dim = 2))
dat[1,]
# [1] 0.2489993 0.6595176
set.seed(5)
dat = rCopula(50, gumbelCopula(2.07, dim = 2))
dat[1,]
# [1] 0.2489993 0.6595176
```

Why does it happen and how can I get the same numbers?

Comment: What are this different sessions?

Comment: @Pascal I can't reproduce what the OP has.  I always get the same values for the same seed (which intuitively is what we would expect).  Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I always get the same results, with the same values you show in your answer, i.e. `[1] 0.3529631 0.2502620`. That's why I asked for these sessions.

Comment: You were right, I posted too quickly.  Let's see what he says.

Comment: Could we kindly have the requested information? We are not able to reproduce this behavior.